# I wanna show a collection of fields dependent on the selected value of a pick list,while creating a new instance of an object

Tags: visualforce, field-dependencies

Is it possible to have some fields render on the basis of values of a pick list?
Right now i am using a vf page to achieve the same,but it is not working as expected.
My code is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <apex:form>
      <apex:outputPanel id="t1">
            <apex:pageBlock>
                  <apex:pageBlockSection>
                         <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Type}"/> 
                                     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="t1" />
                        <apex:inputField id="Name" value="{!Account.Name}"   rendered="{!Account.Type == 'Prospect'}"/>
                        <apex:inputField id="Industry" value="{!Account.Industry}"   rendered="{!Account.Type == 'Prospect'}"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockSection>
              </apex:pageBlock> 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to bind the `<apex:actionSupport />` to the component `<apex:inputField />` by wrapping it.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Type}"> 
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="t1" />
</apex:inputField>
```

Comment: I wanna use that functionality while creating a new Account ,i.e the other fields are made visible only when Type is set to Prospect.Is it possible?

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena It is certainly possible